# Installing Azure Antimalware Extension to an existing Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I am trying to install the **Microsoft Antimalware** extension to an existing virtual machine.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

### Using Visual Studio

1) Connect to Azure from VS

2) Select Server from Virtual Machines

3) Open Configuration properties.

4) Select Microsoft Antimalware from extensions and click Add.

5) Click Update. Outputs...

> > Updating virtual machine myVM...
> >
> > Failed to update virtual machine. The probe setting for the endpoint group HTTP-80 is null. An external endpoint HTTP cannot specify a probe setting.

### Using PowerShell

When following these [MS instructions](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/13/deploying-antimalware-solutions-on-azure-virtual-machines/) to install Antimalware using the Powershell , I get the error:

```
PS C:\> Update-AzureVM -Name $service -ServiceName $name -VM $vm.VM

Update-AzureVM : Could not find a deployment for 'myVM' in 'Production' slot.
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-AzureVM -Name $service -ServiceName $name -VM $vm.VM
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Update-AzureVM], ApplicationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.UpdateAzureVMCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install antimalware via the powershell:

Make sure you are using the latest Azure Powershell version (version 0.8.12)

```
 Get-Module
```

Now create a configuration file on disk in json format:

```
 $JsonString="{ 'AntimalwareEnabled': true }"
 $JsonString |Out-File $home\downloads\AzureAntimalware.json
```

Then select and update your VM:

```
 Get-AzureVM -Servicename "myService" -Name "myVM" | Set-AzureVMMicrosoftAntimalwareExtension -AntimalwareConfigFile $home\downloads\AzureAntimalware.json | Update-AzureVM
```

This will install System Center Endpoint Protection onto the virtual machine.

When you try and launch System Center Endpoint Protection from the start menu you may be presented with the following error message:

```
 Your system administrator has restricted access to this app.
```

To fix this issue, open a command prompt on the VM and enter:

```
 cd "c:/program files/microsoft security client"

 configsecuritypolicy cleanuppolicy.xml
```

This will create the necessary config files and fix the problem.

You will now be able to launch System **Center Endpoint Protection** from the start menu and configure the program in the usual way.

Comment: Seems to work fine also with the cleanuppolixy.xml, but any idea if it could be easily reverted w/o uninstall/install of the Extension?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late replying so you've probably solved the issue.

This is how I resolved it using Powershell:

- http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=394789&clcid=0x409 – Download the VM agent and install on the virtual machine
- Activate the VM agent with the following:

`$vm = Get-AzureVM –serviceName $svc –Name $name
$vm.VM.ProvisionGuestAgent = $TRUE
Update-AzureVM –Name $name –VM $vm.VM –ServiceName $svc`

- You can check if it’s running by opening task manager and clicking the details tab – Look for WaAppAgent.exe, WindowsAzureGuestAgent.exe, WindowsAzureTelemetryService.exe
- Once running you can install AntiMalware with the following:

```
    $servicename = "<SERVICE NAME HERE>"
    $name = "<NAME HERE>"

    # Get the VM
    $vm = Get-AzureVM –ServiceName $servicename –Name $name

    # Add Microsoft Antimalware Agent to the Virtual Machine
    Set-AzureVMExtension -Publisher Microsoft.Azure.Security -ExtensionName IaaSAntimalware -Version 1.* -VM $vm.VM

    # Update the VM which will install the Antimalware Agent
    Update-AzureVM -Name $servicename -ServiceName $name -VM $vm.VM
```

- You can check it works by looking in services.msc for Microsoft Antimalware service